# PHP month format conversion from numeric to String

Tags: php, date

I have months in this format : 07,06,05,04,03,02. I want to convert them to : July, Jun, May, April, March, February.

Actually I need a drop down listing of 6 months back from the current date.

```
<select>
   <option value="07">July</option>
   <option value="06">June</option>
   <option value="05">May</option>
   <option value="04">April</option>
   <option value="03">March</option>
   <option value="02">February</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Datetime class if you have latest PHP,
else,

Try this, and apply your logic accordingly. Its example for December.

```
echo date('F', strtotime(date('Y-12-d')));
```

Comment: Thank you very Much. This script solve my issue

Comment: @BikramPahi,  you're welcome, please vote-up if this has solved your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can get today's date and modify it while looping.

```
$d = new Datetime();
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){

    echo $d->format('m'); // numeric
    echo $d->format('M'); // short string   
    echo $d->format('F'); // long string  
    $d->modify('-1 MONTH');
}
```

Comment: The correct way to do this. +1

Answer (score 2):

YOu can use an array for this -

```
$months = array(
'01' => 'January',
'02' => 'February',
....
);

echo $months[$yourVal];
```